# How to amplify sawtooth wave?

Tags: circuit-design, analog, sawtooth-waveform

I have to amplify the sawtooth wave from 0-7V to 0-14V with its waveform intact. I tried to amplify the wave using op-amps, MOSFET but the waveform shape changes. I'm new to analog circuit design, it will be helpful if you could suggest any IC or method to amplify sawtooth wave or should I completely change my approach?

Required specification of sawtooth: 0-14V and 50kHz, error allowed in *Vpeak,Vbottom,Vpp,frequency*<3% and *tfall/trise*<2%
Max Supply Voltage of 555 timer-18V
Max Supply Voltage of LM334 constant current circuit-40V

[image]
**Fig**: Sawtooth waveform generator circuit
[image]
**Fig**:Sawtooth wave(0-7V frequency=50kHz)

Comment: A really decent op-amp should be able to amplify this without much waveform distortion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most reliable way is with an opamp, IMO. Assuming a single power supply, you need any part that has:

- rail to rail output
- down to negative rail input
- at least say 5 MHz GBW product
- slew rate of at least 14 V per ~0.5 us = 28 V/us

As tons of opamps meet those specs, part recommendations are not useful.

Another simple way would be a 1:2 auto-transformer. this can be very small and cheap, unless you need this 0-14V signal to drive a considerable load.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use high speed CMOS Op-Amp (Or rail to rail Op-Amp). Input offset or Rail to Rail operation is not the major issue (as 555 timer's output doesn’t touch zero volt), the operating speed and capacitance (both external & internal) is the main factor.  As you need 0 to 14 volts, you need to find 16 volt CMOS  Op Amp (Or Higher) . Use the component filter of LCSC or Mouser to find the suitable one.

One problem you may face because of the offset voltage created by  TTL 555 timer. CMOS Op amp will amplify it and hence you may use a differential amplifier to eliminate the DC offset.